# Position dependent code

Tags: gcc, sparc, fpic

I am using a processor that uses sparc v8 architecture. I would like to compile my executable such that each function call is absolute address. Using -fPIC option generate position independent code, is there any reverse of this flag ?

Answer (score 2):

Most of GCC options have both `-fxxx` and `-fno-xxx` variants.

You can easily test if this is the case for `fPIC`. Just compile some simple test:

```
int main () { printf ("Hello, world!\n"); }
```

with command line like:

```
gcc -fPIC test.c -S
```

and look for PLT-relative call in assembler

```
    call    puts@PLT
```

Now try to cancel this option with its reverse:

```
gcc -fPIC test.c -S -fno-PIC
```

You will see, that PLT-relative call has gone, so everything works.

Comment: Oh I see. The sparc v8 Instruction set has two instructions for jumping. "call"  for relative jump and "jmpl" for absolute jump. So it must be possible to generate code with absolute jumps. I tried just now with the sparc gcc with -fno-pic. Even though code compiles it still generates pic code. Do I need to pass this flag to linker also ?

Comment: No, just compiler option. There is difference between fno-PIC and fno-pic (large and small mode). Check compiler line: canceling option shall go last and be in the same case.